# TYPO3 10.4.3: Backend DCE Pages Image upload issue

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, tx-dce

Does anyone know how to solve this issue in version 10.4.3: Backend issue image upload locked?

[image]

Comment: What you have done so far? Please add some more clarification so peoples can understand issue.

Comment: Sounds you're implementing FAL image and probably you have wrong flexform configuration, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63931849/5961782) is solution for TYPO3 10.x.

Comment: Actually, We had added DCE with Image Upload, then we go to the single page Select DCE of the element which we have created then, All though that above message is shown, and our typo3 backend admin all Images was blocked.   Clearly Group of image DCE not working